# How to select one specific parameter from csv file loaded into Python in single row?

Tags: python, list, csv, file

I'm trying to get a single parameter from csv file loaded into python.
I created rows and appended into row variable
File is saved like Column : Fruit, Amount, Price
Apple, 30, 0.5
[image]

```
rows = []
with open("practice_file.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
    print(rows[1])
```

If I do this I get an output, [Apple, 30, 0.5]
How can I get an output which only pulls "Apple"?

Thanks in advance

I couldn't get anything to solved.

Comment: Have you tried changing `rows.append(row)` to `rows.append(row[0])` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `rows[i]` represents an entire row of values.  To get an individual column value from any particular row you would need to index into your row (`row[i][j]`)

In your case (assuming your data is exactly as your image shows), this should work:

```
rows = []
with open("practice_file.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
    print(rows[0][0])
```

You could also store just one value from each row to begin with (instead of storing the entire row)

```
rows = []
with open("practice_file.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row[0])
    print(rows[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the file has a header use [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and pull the value using the header/column name as each `row` will be a `dict` of form `{"Fruit": col_val, "Amount": col_val, "Price": col_val}.

```
rows = []
with open("practice_file.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row["Fruit"])
    print(rows)
```